# webgl three.js get mouse position on Mesh

Tags: javascript, cursor, position, three.js, webgl

Honestly, i tried to find solution for question below, please help me. And sorry for my English :)

I have created a map, added a camera + added camera control of all dimensions.

And when I get the position of the cursor relative to the mesh, the position is always different from different angles.

View all code in jsfiddle.net: http://jsfiddle.net/BT3g3/

I use Three.js r49.

This code is just responsible for calculating the position.

```
function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(  ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 1);
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

    var ray = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );
    var intersect = ray.intersectObject( island );  

    if ( intersect.length > 0) { // !!
        document.getElementById('z').value = intersect[0].point.z;
        document.getElementById('x').value = intersect[0].point.x;
    }
}
```

I was browsing internet and came across [an article](http://www.chandlerprall.com/2011/07/dynamic-terrain-without-heightmaps/) where the cursor position is caught on the map, but i fail move this method to my project :(

Please, help!

Comment: Problem solved!!! I changed the "z" to 0.5 in THREE.Vector3(x, y, z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with following ?

```
mouseX = ( ( event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft ) / canvas.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouseY = - ( ( event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop ) / canvas.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
```

Comment: Hi! My webgl project is stretched to full screen. But i tested you script, and when i move the mesh, and move the mouse to the center of this mesh, the coordinates are different from the previous ones.

Comment: Thank you!  All the solutions to this question I have found apply to the canvas occupying the whole browser window.  This works if your canvas only occupies a portion of the browser window.

Comment: BEWARE canvas offset is local from parent.  Instead of offsetLeft better to use getBoundingClientRect() which returns viewport offset object.